# Error: A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, audio, windows-7

I am trying a C++ program to get GUID of end-point audio device.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<mmdeviceapi.h>

void main()
{
   wchar_t asid[100];
   HRESULT res; 

   res=IMMDevice::GetId(asid);      //This line gives ERROR
      if(res==S_OK)
        printf("1");

}
```

Comment: is `IMMDevice::GetId` a static member function? If not, You need an `IMMDevice` instance to call it, something like: `IMMDevice obj; obj.GetId(asid);`. The error and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371407(v=vs.85).aspx) says it is not a static member.

Comment: Additionally you can't do that in `C` as it doesn't know static member functions or even classes at all.

Comment: Were you trying to write C++ code?

Comment: I have to achieve this in C if it is possible. IMMDevice is a structure if I am not wrong. I have tried creating an instance but it says object is not allowed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371407(v=vs.85).aspx link for IMMDevice::GetId()